# Chaquopy 14.0 failed to install yt_dlp in android

Tags: python, android

I am trying to install yt_dlp for extracting video information from youtube link in my android project using the Chaquopy 14.0. But it throws error:

```
Failed to install pycryptodomex from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/92/efd675dba957315d705f792b28d900bddc36f39252f6713961b4221ee9af/pycryptodomex-3.18.0.tar.gz#sha256=3e3ecb5fe979e7c1bb0027e518340acf7ee60415d79295e5251d13c68dde576e (from yt-dlp).
```

Is there any alternative way to do this or how to fix this.

I tried installing using the android gradle:

```
        python {
            version "3.11"
            buildPython "C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe"
            pip {
                install "yt-dlp"
            }
        }
```